# $args Orderby The number

Tags: categories, wp-query, custom-field, order

I have this code

```
$cat_args=array(
'include' => '42,210,21',
'orderby' => '42,210,21',
'order' => 'asc'
 );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
     'showposts' => 1,
     'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
     'caller_get_posts'=>1
 );
```

I want the `orderby` to be the same order of `include`, not by name or id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `get_terms_orderby` filter:

```
add_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', 'wpse156153_get_terms_orderby', 10, 3 );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
remove_filter( 'get_terms_orderby', 'wpse156153_get_terms_orderby', 10, 3 );
```

with

```
function wpse156153_get_terms_orderby($orderby, $args, $taxonomies ) {
    return 'FIELD(t.term_id, ' . $args['include'] . ')';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but what can i put in the variable $taxonomies and $orderby ??

Comment: it's Work 100 % thanks a lot . Good Job :)

Comment: I have been trying to do the same thing here. Could you share your whole codes please? It did not work for me when I add @bonger's suggestion to my functions and made sure to update '$categories=get_categories($cat_args)'